# Stop Facebook games tagging

Tags: facebook, facebook-games, facebook-tags

Since few days I'm receiving a notification which says I've been tagged in a post. The post is:

> *MyFriendName* was saved by a friend in Hidden Shadows. Thank you *MyName*!
>   Your Friend needs You! Help catch the criminals and solve the case.

This is an automatic tag by a game. In five days it tagged me like 15 times and I don't want it to continue. How can I stop being tagged by games on Facebook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the app is Hidden Shadows. You can go here: https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/playhiddenshadows , and click on **Block**, then **Confirm**.

[image: Screenshot]